# How to display button when checkbox is true if both are from different models.?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to add custom settings in purchase order.

In that I am facing problem to link action of checkbox with button. I am trying to display a button when the checkbox in purchase settings is "True" if not then do not display.

Here's my code:

I am using wizard which inherits purchase.config.settings to add a checkbox "allow_settings"

```
 class ConfigSettingsWizard(models.TransientModel):
   _inherit = 'purchase.config.settings'

   allow_settings = fields.Boolean("settings")
```

inherited_purchase_config_settings_views.xml:

```
<record id="inherited_purchase_config_settings_form_views" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="model">purchase.config.settings</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.view_purchase_configuration"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='group_warning_purchase']" position="after">
            <label string="Setting"/>
            <div>
                <field name="allow_settings" class="oe_inline"/>
                <label for="allow_settings"/>
            </div>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

And a model "Mymodel" which inherit purchase.order

```
 class MyModel(models.Model):
   _inherit = 'purchase.order'
```

xml:

```
<field name="model">purchase.order</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//button[@name='button_cancel']" position="after">
        <button name="add_button" string="Add" type="object" class="btn-primary" />
    </xpath>
</field>
```

Both button and the checkbox are in different models and are inherited from different models.

Is there any way to get data from one model to another model?

Comment: you mean you want to display "add_button" when check box in purchase config "allow_settings" is true?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code.

```
class ConfigSettingsWizard(models.TransientModel):
  _inherit = 'purchase.config.settings'

  allow_settings = fields.Selection([(0, 'Not Visible'),(1, 'Make visible')],
  "Settings", implied_group='your_module.group_name')
```

In xml file:

```
<field name="model">purchase.order</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//button[@name='button_cancel']" position="after">
       <button name="add_button" string="Add" type="object" class="btn-primary" groups="your_module.group_name" />
   </xpath>
</field>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was implement the above solution provided by you. Stucked in creating and adding group to my file. Still trying to figure out what I am mising. I will let you know whether your code worked for me or not. Thank you for your time.

Comment: After selecting value from allow_settings field and saving settings the allow_settings field does not store any value. I have used store=True still after saving if I check that fields value it shows empty drop down.